# Cross-compile-safe way of defining a Rust type representing an opaque C struct whose size is known at compile-time

Tags: rust, ffi, opaque-types

I need to define a Rust type that reflects an opaque C struct whose size and alignment requirements are known at compile-time. A helpful individual suggested I generate code like

```
#[repr(C, align($ALIGNMENT_GOES_HERE))]
pub struct Foo(std::mem::MaybeUninit<[u8; $SIZE_GOES_HERE]>);
```

from a C program, with `$SIZE_GOES_HERE` and friends filled in according to what I determine from there. This works great, but is not at all robust in cases of cross-compilation if the size and alignment are platform-dependent.

Are there any robust solutions for this? The `cc` crate looks promising.

Comment: @eggyal: That's interesting, so thanks! But I'd rather avoid a huge new dependency if possible.

Comment: I can't run it once locally if the very point is for these sizes and alignments to be determiend at compile-time for the machine that is the target :-)

The conditional compilation route is possible, but it would be very labor-intensive and brittle. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sure, bindgen definitely is an option. I was just wondering whether or not I can determine the size and alignment of an opaque C struct at compile-time in a cross-compilation-safe way. Your suggestion of bindgen is great, but my followup question is then whether it's possible to do this *without* introducing a giant new (build-)dependency. It may very well be that the answer to that question is "no". And at any rate, your suggestion is welcome – you couldn't read my mind since I didn't specify the "no extra build-dep" requirement in my question :-)

Comment: Surely I don't need to provide the layout? The *size* and *alignment requirements* shold be enough, right? And these I need to provide, indeed. My question is thus: *assuming that a C compiler could understand the size and alignment from an available header file, can I have Rust automatically do the same (in a way that isn't brittle in the face of cross-compilation)?* (Your answer that bindgen can solve this is a good one – but out of curiosity I'm also interested in suggestions that don't add big new build-deps).

Comment: I guess we should stop this extended discussion in the comments, but if you make the bindgen suggestion an answer, I'll accept it. That way we help out others who may have the same problem :-)

Comment: Have posted as an answer, but by all means leave unaccepted in case anyone else has other ideas.   I'll delete all my comments above to clear up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size and alignment of a given struct for a particular target architecture are determined by the struct's layout and the target architecture's ABI.

If Rust does not have the struct's layout, then it cannot determine its size or alignment—so it must be explicitly furnished with this information.

However, because this information is target-dependent, providing it in advance of compilation will limit the possible targets to those that have been hard-coded (e.g. via different definitions, selected by conditional compilation).

Instead, there is an official tool called [bindgen](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen) that can automatically generate the appropriate Rust binding from the C header file as a build step at compilation-time.  It can be configured to [treat a type as an opaque blob of bytes](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/opaque.html), if so desired.